# Fusermount mounting SSHFS directory works manually but not automatically?

Tags: mount, remote, automounting, sshfs

My workstations run Debian Jessie and *should* automatically mount a remote directory over SSHFS when the user logs on to their desktop. We have a script to do so, located on the user's workstation:

```
#!/bin/bash
fusermount -u ~/remote-directory
sshfs -o reconnect remote@server:/home/shared ~/remote-directory
```

I have tried everything I can think of. I referenced the .sh file in crontab @reboot and rc.local (after changing the tildes to direct paths to the directory), then changed it so that the commands themselves should be run. I have made sure both the .sh and rc.local are executable.

When I reboot the workstation, the directory still does not automatically mount. Checking syslog, I get the following errors:

```
rc.local[3140]: fusermount: failed to unmount /home/user/remote-directory: Invalid argument
systemd-udevd[1592]: Process '/bin/mount -t fusectl fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections' failed with exit code 32.
```

This leads me to believe there is a problem with the -u switch in the fusermount command, but when I run the script manually after login it works perfectly fine. Why won't it *just work* automatically if it works manually?

Comment: Have you thought about using [pam_mount](https://debian-administration.org/article/587/pam_mount_and_sshfs_with_password_authentication)

Comment: @Christopher There is a desktop icon referencing the script that users double click after logging in to run the script. Most of our users are not technically proficient enough to use the terminal.

Comment: @StrongBad No, I've never heard of it. I will look into it. Unfortunately I do not have access to the remote server right now so I cannot really test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was adding the fusermount script to crontab and rc.local, which run the script at startup. Instead, I needed to create a .desktop referencing the script and add it to `/etc/xdg/autostart` - this runs the script when the user logs in, usually after all the requisite services have started and the user credentials can be used to auth sshfs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. After much googling ant trying everything possible, I finally figured out that the problem is weird but simple - just restart the machine after installing sshfs. After restart fusermount stopped complaining and unmounting worked as expected.